# IMAPI2 Error on Windows XP

Tags: c#, imapi

We have developed application for CD/DVD burning. The Application uses microsoft IMAPI2. It works without any problem on Windows 7.

On XP, We rebuilt the application on Windows XP and we received IMAPI2 error (Error screen shot).

We have installed IMAPI2 components on Windows XP. Have we missed any components/registring anything.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.
Harsha[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some suggestions that you need to install [Microsoft Feature Pack for Storage 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19622) to get the IBurnVerification interface.